# Checking on terminal window remotely

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal, remote

I have something working on a computer which is displaying its results (in this case, a very large rsync displaying the files as it goes, but other stuff happens), is there any way i can check on it's progress from a remote ssh connection, or do i have to wait until i can get back to that machine?
I *know* how to check for when it's finished, I'd just like to know where it's at now)

Comment: is the process (whose status you want to check) running on a terminal?

Comment: Yes. It's currently running on "gnome-terminal" (if that matters), but I'd like to see it's progress from my laptop.

Comment: Agreed @muru i was unable to find that when i was looking and it clearly covers my question and what options are (and more importantly, are not) available to me. Thanks.  I did search though just fyi

Comment: You could have run your proccess under `screen` (Read `man screen`) at the very beginnng, but ...

Comment: I could also have just run it remotely.  The point was i didnt know i wanted to check on it, and was feeling out for future reference too.  It wasnt about "could have", it was "what can i do now".